# Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud Platform and I receive the following error when I try to create the cluster from the Web app:

> An unknown error has occurred in Compute Engine: "EXTERNAL: Google
>   Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for
>   'projects/my-project-198766/zones/us-west1-a'". Error code: "18"

When I use gcloud I receive this response:

> (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403,
>   message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission
>   for 'projects/my-project-198766/zones/us-west1-a'

Please note that I have the Owner role and I can create VM instances without any issues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sort of issue might arise if somehow your cloudservices robot gets removed as a project editor. My best guess is that in your case this is the issue.

This might happen due to API call which has *SetIamPolicy* that is missing cloudservices robot from the "roles/editor" bindings. *SetIamPolicy* is a straight PUT, it will override with whatever policy is provided in the request. You can get the list of IAM policies for your project with below command as [given in this article](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy).

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-id]
```

From the list, you can check whether below service account has the editor permission or not.

> [id]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

To fix the issue, you can [grant the mentioned service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members) **"Editor"** permission and check whether that solves the issue or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have the service account with project editor permissions, and my account is the owner role account. and I still can't get gcloud to create a cluster without complaining

Comment: I had to add the following two SAs and give them these roles.

PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Compute Engine default service account), roles: Dataproc Worker, Service Account User

PROJECT_ID@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com (Google APIs Service Agent), roles: Editor

Answer (score 7):

in my case I deleted the service accounts / IAM's or whatever and that very same error message popped up, when I tried to create a kubernetes cluster.

I asked Google to recreate my service accounts, and they mentioned that you can recreate service accounts and their permissions simply by enabling them again. So, in my case I ran the following two commands in order to make kubernetes work again:

```
gcloud services enable compute
gcloud services enable container
```

Here is the link they gave me:
https://issuetracker.google.com/64671745#comment2

Comment: id disabled and then enabled the service using the above and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 5):

I think I got it. I tried to follow the advice from [GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24045#issuecomment-301530235). The permissions I needed to set on my account (called `blahblah-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) were:

`roles/compute.instanceAdmin
roles/editor
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

The last one seemed to be crucial.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @Taher, that's most likely due to missing permissions for [Google managed service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed). If after checking the IAM policies for your project with `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-id]` you do not see the permissions listed, then you can add the required permissions by running the following:

```
project_id=[your-project-id]
project_number=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format='value(projectNumber)')

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $project_id \
  --member="serviceAccount:service-$project_number@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/compute.serviceAgent"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $project_id \
  --member="serviceAccount:service-$project_number@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/container.serviceAgent"
```

The full list of Google managed service accounts (service agents) is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents).

Answer (score 0):

For me recreating the service account with a new name from the console fixed the issue. I have only given the "Editor" role to the service account

Answer (score 0):

I had accidently deleted the compute-service account.  I had to follow all the steps mentioned above ie.

1. undelete the compute-service account
2. add the permission back to the service account - editor, serviceaccountuser, computeinstanceAdmin
3. Enable again compute and container services.  Although these were not disabled, running gcloud services enable compute container, created some default service accounts for the compute robot such as service-@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com and service-@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
As of now I guess from G Console its not possible to add above specified roles.I have recreated another key and added the role compute.admin to resolve the issue.

$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
--iam-account new-sa@some-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com

The above command will create and download the key for this service account in a JSON format.

$ gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding some-project-name \
--member serviceAccount:new-sa@some-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/compute.admin

This command will assign compute.admin role to new-sa service account.

$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json

$ gcloud compute instances list
```

Answer (score -1):

for me exporting the path for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= resolved the issue