# Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.instances.get' permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, circleci

I am trying to connect to GCloud using CircleCI and deploy my code. I can successfully authenticate my service account user using:

```
gcloud --quiet auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
        gcloud --quiet config set project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}
        gcloud --quiet config set compute/zone ${GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE}
```

However, when I try to use the code below to deploy:

```
gcloud --quiet compute scp --recurse /[Folder_name] [Instance_Name]:/var/www/test --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --project [Project_Name]
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
- Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for [Instance_name]
```

I have looked at the rights and looks like the service user has admin rights, which should include instances.get permission as well according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/).

[image]

I think my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232189/google-compute-engine-required-compute-zones-get-permission-error); however, the solution proposed there is not working, which is why I am asking a separate question. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's the same project? What do you get when running `gcloud auth list`?

Comment: I realized it was a different project id with a similar project name and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new service account in the console rather than using the default compute service account.

Export the JSON file and follow this guide - works for me.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/google-auth/