# gcloud app deploy Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for Owner Principal

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

```
$ gcloud app deploy MY.yaml --image-url gcr.io/vorburger-learn-appengin/image:develop
```

causes the following error for me:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request to https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projects/vorburger-learn-appengin/regions/europe-west1?key failed, details: Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/vorburger-learn-appengin/regions/europe-west1'`

I'm simply running gcloud locally after `gcloud init` for my `@gmail.com` account, who has the omnipotent IAM *Owner* role on that GCP project. So it's not clear to me just **which** IAM Principal is missing the `compute.regions.get` permission?

This is on a project where it used to work last year and stopped working 2 months ago. Maybe I deleted something by mistake? Things I've tried out so far:

- `gcloud services enable appengineflex.googleapis.com` [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779124/421602)
- Verified `@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` *Google APIs Service Agent* exists and has the *Editor* role [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236384/421602)
- I do NOT have any `123...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` account [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290341/421602) on this project - should I?

Background: https://github.com/vorburger/www.fineract.dev/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

> I do NOT have any 123...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account mentioned here on this project - should I?

Yes, you have to [undelete the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting). However, the `undelete` command only works for Service Accounts deleted fewer than 30 days ago.

> After 30 days, IAM permanently removes the service account. Google Cloud cannot recover the service account after it is permanently removed, even if you file a support request.

If you are not able to undelete the service account, you can create a new service account with the same name; revoke all of the roles from the deleted service account; and grant the same roles to the new service account. For details, see [Policies with deleted principals](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#handle-deleted-members).

Additionally, you did not mention the [App Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/default-service-account) if it was also accidentally deleted. If yes, you would also need to undelete this.

> Warning: Deleting the App Engine default service account breaks any current and future App Engine applications in your Cloud project. For example, your application will lose access to other Google Cloud services such as Datastore. If needed, you can restore a deleted default service account.

Comment: The `...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` Service Account itself seems to just have magically re-appeared now, but it didn't have any Permissions, so I've granted it Editor role (again, I guess).

The `vorburger-learn-appengin@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` App Engine default Service Account was still present and still had Editor permission.

However, unfortunately it still does not work... :-( Still the same error. Any clue as to why, or suggestion how to further debug it?

Comment: @vorburger have you set this [service account as the default](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/project-info/set-default-service-account) in your project?

Comment: `gcloud alpha compute project-info set-default-service-account --service-account=123...789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` fails with _ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.project-info.set-default-service-account) HTTPError 403: Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'_. How can I grant _Owner_ this permissions

Comment: You would need to file for a request to get an Alpha access. Though you can also try to edit your VM and update the service account field.

Comment: How/where does one raise such a request? https://console.cloud.google.com/support only has Community support (for this project, this is a funded open source project) - which would be here, on StackOverflow.